# How to use HTML 5 validation?

Tags: html, validation

If any field is empty it shows "please fill this field" and for password it gives error message if password not match "Password not match".

```
<form  method="GET">
          <p>Please Add Information</p>
          <input type="text" name="fname" id="first_name"  placeholder=" First Name" value="">
            <input type="text" name="lname" id="last_name"  placeholder=" Last Name"  value="">
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder=" Email" value="" >
            <input type="text" name="mob_number" id="mobile_no"  placeholder=" Mobile Number" value="">
            <input type="text"  placeholder=" City Name" name="city" id="city">
            <textarea col="6" row="15" name="address" placeholder=" Address"></textarea>
    <input type="password" id="password1" placeholder="Password" name="password">
    <input type="password" id="password2"  placeholder="Confirm Password" >

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "HTML 5 validation"? Do you mean checking password with javascript? PHP? ASP? Java?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript for form validation.  Put an empty `<span id="validate"></sapn>` tag behind the element you want to validate, and something like `onblur="myFunction()"` statement in your input field.  Use whatever id and function name you like.  In your `<head>` section you could do 
    `function myFunction(){
       var password1 = document.getElementById('password1').value;
       var password2 = document.getElementById('password2').value;
       if(password1 != password2){
          document.getElementById('validate').innerHTML = 'Passwords do not match';
       }else{
          document.getElementById('validate').innerHTML = ' ';
       }
    }`

If you modify that code some, you can use it to tell your user that they need to fill in the form.

Optionally, if you give your button an id, you can use `document.getElementById('button_name').disabled=true` to disable the button if the passwords do not match.

Answer (score 0):

HTML Validation only really checks to see if the input is valid, not wether it is correct.

For example, "Test@example.com" is a valid email, but extremely unlikely to be 'correct'

For HTML5 validation, a lot of browsers will do that basic checking for you. Beyond that, there is a library called ParsleyJS that I like to use that provides more customizability and options.

Now, if you're looking to see if the information is "correct" you need something to check it against. This really shouldn't be handled client side. If you must, (I believe Apple's iForgot service does this for previously used passwords) you can send a hash of the password, and hash the user's input before checking it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

**Javascript**

```
function checkForm(form) { 
if(form.pwd1.value != form.pwd2.value) { 
alert("Error: Password do not match with Each Other!"); 
return false; 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form ... onsubmit="return checkForm(this);"> 
<p>Username: <input type="text" name="username"></p> 
<p>Password: <input type="password" name="pwd1"></p> 
<p>Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="pwd2"></p> 
<p><input type="submit"></p> 
</form>
```

Hope HTML5 will bring that functionality soon, of comparing two strings. So that we won't have to rely on JavaScript.